# How to open a navcontroller from a non navcontroller view?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios4, uinavigationcontroller

I'm coding an iphone app and I've an issue on how to manage views presentation. Indeed, when user starts the app a "home" View shows up containing a search form. When user presses a "search" button I want a method to open a navcontroller that displays the search results. I made another view containing a TableView with the purpose of serving as "results" View. I want the "results" view to allow user to go back to the "home" view (the search form) but I don't want the "home" view to have a navigation controller bar...

Any idea on how to solve this ?

Thx in advance,

Stephane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier way is just to hide the navigation bar on the 'home' view and show it back on the other view...

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a UINavigation controller manually and present it modally as follows:

```
MapViewController *mapViewController = [[[MapViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mapViewController];

[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```